At about what number of observations does the difference in the z and t distributions become practically meaningless?
At about what number of observations does the difference in the z and t distributions become practically meaningless? Is it 30 or 100?

Define "practically meaningless"

Well, it all depends on what you mean by "meaningless". Which depends on what you would find to be "close enough", for whatever conclusion you would want to make (i.e. how much precision you would need). So there is no 1 particular sample size above which the difference becomes meaningless.
One simple way to get a feel for how close the 2 become (and then decide if it is close enough for your application), as the sample size increases is to calculate t-values for different sample sizes, and compare it to the z-value. Let's use the "typical" $z_{.025}=1.959964$ as an example:
For $n=20$, we have $t_{.025}=2.093024$, or a difference of 6.8%. Is that too much? For a back of the enveloppe calculation, probably not; but for a published result, certainly yes.
For $n=30$, the difference becomes 4.35%, $n=50$, it is 2.53%, $n=100$ it becomes 1.24%, it drops below 1% at $n=125$, and reaches 0.012% at $n=1000$ (which I think everyone would agree becomes insignificant).
You can play with this critical value calculator to get a feel for it yourself.
But... there is a caveat. When the only tool researchers had was a z-table (which can fit on a single page), approximating t-values with z-values was pragnmatic (t-tables needed a page per possible sample size...). But that was before computers (or even statistical caculators, i.e. when dinosaurs still roamed the earth). Now that we have these tools, there is really no excuse or reason for continuing to use z as an "approximation" of t, no matter what the sample size is. It is a bit akin to asking how many digits to use for $\pi$? As many as your software affords you (why not, they are "free").

I will add to the previous answer by pointing out that it matters how far out in the tail you are looking.  In genome-wide association studies, we were working with tail probabilities on the order of $10^{-8}$ and you need much larger df to get good approximation of a $t$ by a Normal distribution out there.

It depends on what you are looking for.
Here are density plots for a standard normal distribution in black, and for $t$ distribution in red with $1$ to $100$ degrees of freedom (in the centre, $1$ degree of freedom is the lowest density while at the edges it is the highest). It does not take many degrees of freedom for the $t$ distribution density to be close to the normal density, i.e. with small absolute differences. For example, with $14$ or more degrees of freedom, the density differ in absolute magnitude by less than $0.01$ (so less than a fortieth of the peak density).

But if you plot the same density curves with a log-scale, even with $100$ degrees of freedom you not close in the tails, i.e. there are large relative differences there (a factor of more than $10$ at $\pm 6$), and it gets worse further out in the tails. In the centre, similarly to the absolute difference, this is much less of an issue.


thank you very  much

Two good answers already. I think one useful tool for seeing where the difference is "meaningless" for your purposes and at the tail position you need is to make a density plot of the various distributions. You can find such plots in many basic statistics books, but it should be easy enough to make your own with any good statistics software.And that would make it very flexible; you could look at any sample sizes and zoom in on any area of the distribution.
But, to reiterate the points made above: 1) It is situation and field dependent. In the fields that I worked in (mostly social sciences) n = 30 was a good guide (I am old enough that I still had to look in tables). There was so much error in the models and measures. But if you were in a field were high precision measurement was possible and models could be simple, then you would want more.
And I am just barely old enough to remember using those tables. By the time I was writing my dissertation, they were passe. As jginestat says, you can easily use t with any df you like. The computer won't care.

Thank you, Sir! Do you think I can make density plots on Stata? Best,
